# Scroll UITableView to bottom when using estimated row heights

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm having a problem that seems like it shouldn't really be a problem. I'm trying to create a comments ("chat") view for my app, but I'm using estimated row heights and can't find a nice way to have the comments start at the bottom, such that when the view is loaded, the latest comment is at the bottom of the screen, just above the input area also at the bottom of the screen.

I've been looking around for ages and have found solutions like these:

```
[self.tblComments scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];
```

Doesn't work nicely because it uses the estimated row height, which isn't always right (some comments will be much longer).

```
[self.tblComments setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(self.tblComments.bounds.size.height - self.tblComments.contentSize.height, 0, 0, 0)];
```

Same problem as above (contentSize is determined by estimatedRowHeight).

I'm sure there's a perfect solution to this somewhere since so many apps have views like this, I just can't find it. I'd love any insight into something I may be missing here...

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean when you say "latest comment sticks to the bottom of the screen". Do you just want to scroll to the bottom of the table when someone enters a comment? Or do you want to scroll to the start of that last comment?

Comment: Ah ye I shouldn't have said sticks, I mean 'starts at the bottom'. Much like every other chat app in the world - the latest entry is at the bottom right above the input area.

Comment: OK, so you're inputting from the bottom and want each new comment to come up right above the input. What's happening now? Meaning, what exactly is the currently problem?

Comment: Basically, i want a function that will scroll my uitableview to the bottom

Comment: As I mentioned, the two methods above work but have huge caveats in that they depend on the estimatedRowHeight. I want a solution that doesn't.

Comment: Does `[table setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, CGFLOAT_MAX)]` not do what you want?

Comment: Well, that just pads the top of my content with loads of empty space so the user can keep scrolling up into emptiness pretty much forever, which I don't want.

Comment: @krishan711 ^ And I understand why that's happening too. Just give me a sec to write out an updated answer.

Comment: did you ever find an answer to your question?

Comment: @user3498976 not a perfect solution - I disabled estimated row heights and got it to work. Would love to hear a better solution if you have one though?

Answer (score 2):

Edit:

`contentSize` is simply ["The size of the content view."](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiscrollview_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScrollView/contentSize) But since you've set a value for `estimatedRowHeight`, all your off-screen cells are assumed to be of height `estimatedRowHeight`.

According to the docs, here's the point of `estimatedRowHeight`:

> Providing a nonnegative estimate of the height of rows can improve the performance of loading the table view. If the table contains variable height rows, it might be expensive to calculate all their heights when the table loads. Using estimation allows you to defer some of the cost of geometry calculation from load time to scrolling time.

So basically, in order to save time, the table is making an assumption about row height and thus content size based on your `estimatedRowHeight`. By using `estimatedRowHeight` you're asking your `UITableView` to make these "shortcuts" in order to improve performance. You're basically telling the program not to calculate the row heights ahead of time, so in order to get the row heights and content sizes of any off-screen content, you have to calculate them manually. As long as you decide to set an `estimatedRowHeight`, this is unavoidable.

My guess is that many chat apps you've looked at don't use `estimatedRowHeight` in order to avoid this issue...

But if you do in fact feel as if using `estimatedRowHeight` helps with your app's performance, here are two suggestions.

**SUGGESTION #1**

Perhaps it makes sense to have a `totalChatHeight` variable where you keep track of the total row heights as they come in, calculated using similar logic as your `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` method. By originally calculating this info in the background as the comments load then incrementing as you go, you'd still maintain the performance benefits of using `estimatedRowHeight` without sacrificing the functionality of having the table know its row heights.

By doing this, you can structure your `contentOffset` statement like so to scroll to the bottom using the known table row height information:

```
CGPoint bottomOffset = CGPointMake(0, totalChatHeight - self.tblComments.frame.size.height);
[self.tblComments setContentOffset:bottomOffset animated:YES];
```

**SUGGESTION #2**

Another suggestion would be to calculate your row average dynamically so you have a more precise measurement for `estimatedRowHeight` and the `contentSize` of your `UITableView` would approximately be the same with or without using `estimatedRowHeight`. That way `estimatedRowHeight` is *actually* the estimate row height and the estimated content size should also be near the actual `contentSize`, so this standard `contentOffset` formula should work:

```
CGPoint bottomOffset = CGPointMake(0, self.tblComments.contentSize.height - self.tblComments.frame.size.height);
[self.tblComments setContentOffset:bottomOffset animated:YES];
```

This could potentially be dangerous though as both the chat log and rounding error grow.

**SUGGESTION #3 <-- Perhaps the best way to go in this case**

This third suggestion may be the easiest to implement in your case as it doesn't require any ongoing calculations:

*Just set `estimatedRowHeight` to the last row's height before reloading the table's data.*

You can calculate that new row's height using whatever algorithm you use in `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` then set `estimatedRowHeight` to that height; that way you can use this statement to scroll to the last cell

```
[self.tblComments scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];
```

and even though, as you said, it determines the row position based on `estimatedRowHeight`, it should scroll to the correct position as long as the `estimatedRowHeight` equals the bottom row height.

Comment: contentSize is determined by the estimated row height for each cell. But as you may imagine some people leave long comments and others leave short comments, so the estimated height is often wrong. This results in either the view being overscrolled or underscrolled. Please read the question I have already tried this.

Comment: @krishan711 No. Contentsize in this case includes the entire content size of the UITableView. It does not depend on estimated row height.  You tried contentInset, not contentOffset.

Comment: @krishan711 I've edited my comment to hopefully clear up your confusion. Try my code. You have NOT tried it yet. You were using content*Inset*, which is wrong.

Comment: Well, I have tried contentOffset too now as well and it produces EXACTLY the same result. How do you think contentSize is determined?

Comment: @krishan711 Content Size is simply the size of the content view: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiscrollview_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScrollView/contentSize

Comment: @krishan711 Where in your code are you calling reload data? Could you add that code to your answer? Are you also posting to a server in the process? I'm asking in order to find out whether any of your code is async and thus could account for the lag in getting the row's content.

Comment: In a UITableView the contentSize is determined by the estimated row height, thats the problem. I know for sure because if I change the estimated row height to (e.g.) 500 and use the code you suggest the content size is still exactly 500 * number of rows.

Comment: @krishan711 Oh, I see why you're confused now. Give me a second and I'll update my answer. My recent update was an oversimplification.

Comment: Just to clarify, I'm not confused about anything. I know exactly why the things I posted do what they do (as I have said in the question). I'm asking for somebody to provide me with an alternate solution.

Comment: @krishan711 I see what you're saying now. I edited your question a little bit to make the issue a little bit clearer for future answer seekers. The problem was that you're purposefully using estimated row heights but you didn't really explain that as the issue in your title or question, so I changed that. Feel free to go back and edit my changes though if you feel as if they're incorrect.

Comment: @krishan711 I added a 3rd suggestion to my update. I think that's the way to go in your case.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. They can all be summarised into one though which is to force calculation of the height for each row, something I don't really want to do. If nobody gives a better solution though I will accept your answer...

Comment: @krishan711 The last suggestion doesn't require you to calculate each row so that's why I recommend that one in your case. Just set estimatedRowHeight to the last row's height before reloading the table's data.

Comment: @krishan711 The fact of the matter is though, if you use estimatedRowHeight, you're basically telling the program not to calculate the row heights ahead of time. That's why you have to do it yourself manually no matter what. It's unavoidable.